# Is it possible to hide the Title on all pages in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, sitepages

I don't want the Title to display on the page as I have the name of the page on the image.

Is it possible to hide the Title on all pages in SharePoint?

Comment: Ganesh Sanap...thank you so much. One more question please...is it possible to lock the display settings so that the Sharepoint site displays at 80% for all Users

Comment: There is no way to make the Sharepoint site displays at 80% for all Users, it depends on page customization for each user.

Comment: Hi @NoeleneBenjamin, does my below answer helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using PowerShell**:

You can remove header and title area from SharePoint online modern experience page using PowerShell.

You have to set the page layout to "Home" like (example using PnP PowerShell):

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName -UseWebLogin
Set-PnPPage -Identity "MyPage" -LayoutType "Home"
```

---

**2. Using SharePoint UI**:

If you don't want to use PowerShell, you can do it from SharePoint UI as well. You have to create the copy of existing SharePoint default home page (without header and title) and use it as a new site page.

Follow below article for detailed steps: [SharePoint Online: Create a blank page without header & title](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/26/sharepoint-online-create-a-blank-page-without-header-and-title/)